# CakePHP 3.0 - helper - form label from field definition

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, helper

Is there a way to make the CakePHP bake command assign the field description (as it is on the database) as the labels of a form?

For example, if the table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `equipment` (
  `equ_pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `equ_desc` varchar(60) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Description',
  `equ_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Code',
  PRIMARY KEY (`equ_pk`),
  UNIQUE KEY `equ_code_UNIQUE` (`equ_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then in the labels of the form would be "Description" and "Code".

By default, the bake command make them "equ_desc" and "equ_code".

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible with bake as it sounds like a rather bespoke situation (someone correct me if I'm wrong). However, you can alter your baked forms and override the labels generated using the `label` option on the form inputs like this:-

```
<?= $this->Form->input('equ_desc', ['label' => __('Description')]) ?>
```

This would give you the desired labels.

Comment: It would be possible using customized bake templates, where one could fed the `label` option with the `comment` key from the schema definition in case it exists. ps. I wish people would forget about that CakePHP 1/2 field name model prefix stuff ;)

Comment: @ndm, my bad on the model prefix I originally misread the version number in the question and should have gone back and fixed my answer. Have done now.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.